# How to send custom error message for Exception in SAP PI/PO 7.5

Tags: exception, integration, sap-pi

In SAP PI/PO 7.5 , I have a SOAP to REST Scenario, In the REST Receiver channel , I have set Network Connection time out, and Socket Time out to 10secs ( a requirement ) , and in the Error Handling Tab, I have added a new entry for Exception , below screenshot :
[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVO7x.png)

When a socket timed out exception does happen, instead of this error message, I am getting this output in the communication channel error log :

[communication channel log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLEmq.png)

Can any one here try to explain what is the reason behind this error ?
Thanks.

I have tried to remove the custom error message and just put an error has happend , but it is still the same,

I tried searching for online blogs for this error, but I was unable to find any which suits to this scenario.